# webpack middleware excessive build calls

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I've got webpack 2 dev middleware's running in my express node server and for some reason, there're excessive calls to wepback builder from a SINGLE CHANGE  (builder should run once per change), this did not happen in webpack 1 on similar configuration; I'm not finding exactly why this to happen.

Here's the server.js:

```
var babel = require('babel-polyfill'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router(),
    port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000,
    dist = path.join(__dirname, ('dist' + (process.env.NODE_ENV ? '/' + process.env.NODE_ENV : 'staging'))),
    superagent = require('superagent'),
    config = require('./config'),
    serverInstance = null,
    chalk = require('chalk')

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    throw err;
})

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    serverInstance.close();
    process.exit(0);
})

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

/**
 * Healthcheck
 */
app.use('/healthcheck', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        'env': {
            'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
        }
    });
    res.end();
});

router.use('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    superagent
        .get('https://jsonip.com/')
        .end(function (err, response) {
            res.send(response.body);
        });
});

// router order matters

// HMR only in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'staging') {
    console.log('Development environment: Starting webPack middleware...');

    var webpack = require('webpack'),
        webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware'),
        webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware'),
        webpackDevConfig = require('./webpack.dev.config'),
        compiler = webpack(webpackDevConfig),
        _ = require('lodash');

    var devMiddleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: webpackDevConfig.output.publicPath,
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            hash: false,
            version: true,
            timings: false,
            assets: false,
            chunks: false,
            modules: false,
            reasons: false,
            children: false,
            source: false,
            errors: true,
            errorDetails: true,
            warnings: true,
            publicPath: false
        }
    });

    router.use(devMiddleware);

    router.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
        log: console.log
    }));

    router.use(function (req, res, next) {
        const reqPath = req.url
        // find the file that the browser is looking for
        const file = _.last(reqPath.split('/'))
        if ([webpackDevConfig.output.filename, 'index.html'].indexOf(file) !== -1) {
            res.end(devMiddleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(webpackDevConfig.output.path, file)));
        } else if (file.indexOf('.') === -1) {
            // if the url does not have an extension, assume they've navigated to something like /home and want index.html
            res.end(devMiddleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(webpackDevConfig.output.path, 'index.html')));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });

} else {

    //Production needs physical files! (built via separate process)
    router.use('/assets', express.static(dist));


    // any other is mapped here
    router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

        // Catch-all route after the ones you want to exclude like the example before '/' 
        // or exclude it here (this has the advantage of ordering however you'd like)
        if (req.url === '/foo' || req.url === '/bar') {
            return next()
        };

        res.sendFile(path.join(dist, 'index.html'));
    });
}

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use('/', router);

serverInstance = app.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }
    console.log(chalk.green('[' + config.build_name + '] listening on port ' + port + '!'));
});
```

The webpack.dev.config file:

```
    var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './js/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/assets'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        // enable HMR on the server
        hot: true,
        // match the output path
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        // match the output `publicPath`
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]?[hash]&outputPath=/assets/&publicPath=/assets/'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: __dirname + '/src/' + 'index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        // enable HMR globally
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

The output in the console:

```
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 714ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 112ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 107ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 104ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 102ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 112ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 99ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 98ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 106ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 106ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 98ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 103ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 105ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 98ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 97ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 102ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 104ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 98ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 97ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 97ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 99ms
webpack building...
webpack built 1052237f44d454edc2fd in 91ms
```

The server is launched by the command `node server.js` and the version of webpack, etc are:

```
"webpack": "^2.2.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0",
```

After upgrading webpack-dev-server to 2.3.0 the problem persists.

Comment: Every time you update your code, webpack will rebuild. If you don't want that behavior disable hot middleware

Comment: C'mon, obviously! The issue is the excessive number of build calls from a single change. Get it?

Comment: I am having the same issue. did you find anything? Do I have a problem in my config or this is the normal behavior?